# {:amqp_msg, {:P_basic, ...:undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined} AMQP error :(

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, elixir, amqp, exrabbitpool

Error I am getting

```
{:amqp_msg, {:P_basic, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, 1, :undefined, 
:undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, 
:undefined, :undefined, :undefined}
```

Error type `:exit`

This happens under the load testing, when I am trying to publish a message into the queue.
I am using ExRabbitPool which has AMQP as it's underlying call out.

If I have 30 requests per seconds, all fine, when start going over it then I start getting errors.

I am using seperate pool for Producer and Consumer and there are enough channels for them. Here are some code

```
 def queue_config, do: [
    queue_name: "some_queue_name",
    exchange: "some_exchange_name",
    queue_options: [durable: true],
    exchange_options: [type: :topic],
    bind_options: [routing_key: "some_routing_name"]
  ]
```

```
ExRabbitPool.with_channel(pool_id, fn {:ok, channel} ->
        try do
          with :ok <- ExRabbitPool.RabbitMQ.declare_exchange(channel, exchange, exchange_options),
                :ok <- ExRabbitPool.RabbitMQ.publish(channel, exchange, routing_key, Jason.encode!(message), options) do
            Logger.info "Published message to the queue #{queue_name}"

            {:ok, message}
          else
            {:error, reason} -> Logger.error("Error publishing message to queue #{pool_id} #{queue_name} #{inspect reason}")
            {:error, reason}
          end
        catch type, error ->
          msg = %{message: "Fatal error occurred when publishing to the queue #{pool_id} #{queue_name} #{inspect type} #{inspect error}", error: error}
          Logger.error(Exception.format(type, msg, __STACKTRACE__))
          {:error, msg}
        end
      end)
```

Sample Error:

```
06:23:51.304 pid=<0.24534.2> ... [error] ** (exit) %{error: {:normal, {:gen_server, :call, [#PID<0.25408.2>, {:call, {:"basic.publish", 0, "result_exchange", "", false, false}, {:amqp_msg, {:P_basic, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, 1, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined}, "[{\"retry_no\":0,\"service_type\":\"someservice\",\"some_id\":123}]"}, #PID<0.24534.2>}, 60000]}}, message: "Fatal error occurred when publishing to the queue producer_pool some_queue :exit {:normal, {:gen_server, :call, [#PID<0.25408.2>, {:call, {:\"basic.publish\", 0, \"result_exchange\", \"\", false, false}, {:amqp_msg, {:P_basic, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, 1, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined}, \"[{\\\"retry_no\\\":0,\\\"service_type\\\":\\\"someservice\\\",\\\"some_id\\\":123}]\"}, #PID<0.24534.2>}, 60000]}}"}
```

So under the load I get the `Fatal error...`

Code is pretty simple, I think it might be something at the RabbitMQ config? not sure.

What do you think?

Comment: The actual error is that the process you're calling (I think it's the channel process?) is exiting with reason `normal` while handling the publish request. Why it would do that, I don't know...

Comment: No it is not, the error is returning from low level AMQP directly from erlang,